# WebStorm dock tool window right vertical menu to the left one

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

On a given tool window pane I've got two vertical menu toolbars arranged to the left and right sides of the screen. Is there a way to move the rightmost vertical toolbar immediately next to the leftmost one?

[image]